# Why Linux VmSize VmData is larger than estimation from code?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, memory

I want to know how many memory will take when the code is running.
I sum all memory used in my code and use GCC to convert to an executable bin file.

When I run the bin file, and use `cat/proc/$PID/status`, the VmSize VmData is much larger than expected. Even if remove all code but only sleep, the result still is the same,

```
VmPeak:    12816 kB
VmSize:    12816 kB
VmLck:         0 kB
VmPin:         0 kB
VmHWM:       964 kB
VmRSS:       964 kB
VmData:      204 kB
VmStk:       136 kB
VmExe:        56 kB
VmLib:      2100 kB
VmPTE:        48 kB
VmPMD:        12 kB
VmSwap:        0 kB
```

- Why the memory is so large even if no data is in my code? the data I estimate in code should be 40K at most, but VmData is 204K, much larger...
- Why VmData is the same no matter I add #if 0 in code or not? Why not change smaller when added? At least should be 30K smaller I think...
- how to get memory my code is using exactly? Any other ways to test?

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    #if 0 
    extern int ed25519_getpub(unsigned char* public_key, const unsigned char* private_key);
    extern int ed25519_sign(unsigned char* signature,
                    const unsigned char* private_key,
                    const unsigned char* msg, const unsigned long msg_len); // use a large static global 30K array
    extern int ed25519_verify(const unsigned char* signature,
                      const unsigned char* public_key,
                      const unsigned char* msg, const unsigned long msg_len); // use the same 30K array

    int ret = 0;
    unsigned char public_key[32];
    unsigned char private_key[32] = "123456789ABC";
    unsigned char signature[64];
    unsigned char msg[64] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    sleep(20);
    #endif

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        #if 0 
        //compute public key
        ret = ed25519_getpub( public_key, private_key );
        if (0 != ret)
        {
            ret = 1;
        }

        printf("public_key = %s, ret = %d \r\n ", public_key, ret);

        ret = ed25519_sign( signature, private_key, msg, strlen(msg) );
        if (0 != ret)
        {
            ret = 2;
        }

        printf("signature = %s, ret = %d, \r\n", signature, ret);

        //verify sign
        ret = ed25519_verify( signature, public_key, msg, strlen(msg) );
        if (0 != ret)
        {
            ret = 3;
        }

        printf("ed25519_verify ret = %d, \r\n ", ret);
        #endif

        if (0 == (i % 5 ))
        {
            sleep(10);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: suggest you start by posting the code that is giving you the problem.  Otherwise how do you expect us to help you debug the problem?

Comment: ok, the code is posted

Comment: the posted code is missing the the statement: `#include <unistd.h>`  that is needed to expose the prototype for the function: `sleep()`

Answer (score -1):

that mass of code boils down to: (because most of it is eliminated via the `'#if 0' ... '#endif' sequences)

```
#include <unistd.h> // for the 'sleep()' function


int main( void )
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        if ( 0 == (i % 5 ) )
        {
            sleep(10);
        }
    }
}
```

where: I'm compiling on ubuntu linux 18.02

here is how I compiled the code:

```
gcc -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 -c "untitled2.c"
```

here is how I linked the code:

```
gcc -ggdb -Wall -o "untitled2" "untitled2.c"
```

Note: the `-ggdb` is so the code would contain the max debugging information for the `gdb` debugger

after compiling/linking, the resulting executable size can be found by:

```
 ls -al untitled2.c
```

which results in:

```
 -rwxrwxrwx 1 richard richard 182 Mar  4 20:54 untitled2.c
```

182 bytes does not look like 204k nor 40k

Please post your compiler, your OS, and did you compile + link into a `dynamic`(the default) executable or a `static` executable

Comment: when you mark down an answer, post a comment as to why

Comment: the run time memory foot print will depend on several factors.  including: 1) are the needed library functions already in memory, how long is the stack, how much file scope memory does the OS allocate, and much more  Overall, a meaningless number that can change depending on external circumstances